# Classic C. Using execvp and pipes. Redirect stdin and sdout

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, exec

I have a follow-up question to this one: [Classic C. Using pipes in execvp function, stdin and stdout redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13801175/5143652)

I need to do the same, but with more than two commands.
If I execute `ls | head | wc` it doesnt work.

My approach is, that all the commands between the first and the last one need to get input from the pipe and output it to the pipe.
My code looks like this:

```
if(i != 0 && i < notoken - 1) {
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);  //closing stdout
            dup(pipefd[1]);         //replacing stdout with pipe write 
            close(STDIN_FILENO);   //closing stdin
            dup(pipefd[0]);         //replacing stdin with pipe read
            close(pipefd[0]);       //closing pipe read
            close(pipefd[1]);

            argv[0] = token[i];
            argv[1] = NULL;
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("failed");
            exit(1);
    } else if(i == 0 && notoken > 1) {
        if(fork() == 0) {          //first fork
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);  //closing stdout
            dup(pipefd[1]);         //replacing stdout with pipe write 
            close(pipefd[0]);       //closing pipe read
            close(pipefd[1]);

            argv[0] = token[i];
            argv[1] = NULL;
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        if(fork() ==0) {
            close(STDIN_FILENO);   //closing stdin
            dup(pipefd[0]);         //replacing stdin with pipe read
            close(pipefd[1]);       //closing pipe write
            close(pipefd[0]);

            argv[0] = token[i];
            argv[1] = NULL;
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a general rule, you need a separate pipe between each pair of processes that want to communicate.  It looks like you're trying to use the same one for each pair.

Comment: Additionally, your middle process needs to associate both its standard input and its standard output with (different) pipes, but right now it's doing only one.

Comment: And for goodness and sanity's sake, use `dup2()` instead of `dup()`!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Would this be right for the "middle" commands with redirected stdin and stdout (SEE ANSWER).